# Convert SQL Server Query to Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to do some reporting out of ALM that is hosted on an Oracle DB.  I have found a query which will hopefully give me some of the information I am trying to get and having difficulty finding an answer for.

However, the query was designed for SQL Server and we are running this on an Oracle DB.  I have tried to update it, but I can only get so far before I hit an error that I cannot resolved (and who knows what else may be after that).

I am stopped at the following error

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 38
```

```
SELECT a.BG_BUG_ID as "Defect-Id",
a.BG_SEVERITY as "Severity",
a.BG_STATUS as "Status",
a.BG_SUMMARY as "Summary",
a.BG_DETECTION_DATE as "Detected on Date",
a.BG_USER_05 as "Resolution",
a.BG_USER_01 as"Product",
a.BG_DETECTION_VERSION as "Detected in Version",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN b.TS_TEST_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(b.TS_TEST_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Test-Id",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN c.RN_RUN_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(c.RN_RUN_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Run-Id",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN d.TC_TESTCYCL_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(d.TC_TESTCYCL_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Test-Instance-Id",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN e.BG_BUG_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(e.BG_BUG_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Linked-Defect-Id", -- there is no need for this ID. You have it in the first selected coulmn
CAST(CASE
 WHEN f.ST_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(f.ST_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "TestStep-Id",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN g.CY_CYCLE_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(g.CY_CYCLE_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Test-Set-Id",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN h.RQ_REQ_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(h.RQ_REQ_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Requirement-Id(Direct Link)",
CAST(CASE
 WHEN i.RC_REQ_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(i.RC_REQ_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Requirement-Id(Coverage Link)"
FROM
BUG a
FULL JOIN LINK l ON (a.BG_BUG_ID = l.LN_BUG_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE IN ("TEST","RUN","TESTCYCL","BUG","STEP","CYCLE", "REQ"))
LEFT JOIN TEST b ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = b.TS_TEST_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "TEST")
LEFT JOIN RUN c ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = c.RN_RUN_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "RUN")
LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL d ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = d.TC_TESTCYCL_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "TESTCYCL")
LEFT JOIN BUG e ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = e.BG_BUG_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "BUG")
LEFT JOIN STEP f ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = f.ST_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "STEP")
LEFT JOIN CYCLE g ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = g.CY_CYCLE_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "CYCLE")
LEFT JOIN REQ h ON (l.LN_ENTITY_ID = h.RQ_REQ_ID AND l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = "REQ")
LEFT JOIN REQ_COVER i ON (i.RC_ENTITY_ID = b.TS_TEST_ID AND i.RC_ENTITY_TYPE="TEST")
```

Comment: Replace `"N/A"` with `'N/A'` .. use single quotes.

Comment: SQL Server uses single quotes for string literals just as Oracle does, and probably every other RDBMS which even pretends to adhere to ANSI SQL standards. So if the original query ran on SQL Server surely it must have used single quotes for all those literals (not just N/A but all those entity types in the join criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have commented, there is issue with all `case` statements.

I am showing you how to change it for one such `case` statement, replicate the same changes in all `case` statements.

Original:

```
CAST(CASE
 WHEN b.TS_TEST_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN CAST(b.TS_TEST_ID AS varchar)
 ELSE "N/A"
END AS varchar) as "Test-Id",
```

Change it to:

```
COALESCE(TO_CHAR(b.TS_TEST_ID), 'N/A') as "Test-Id",
```

`COALESCE` will return first non null value from passed parameters list and string literals must be wrapped with `single quotes`.

There is no use of so many `CAST`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you.  This got the query running.  Unfortunately it didn't give me the results i was hoping for.